# Syntax error on full text search

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, full-text-search

I am trying to do a search where the data can match any set of columns.

When I run this

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(80)           = 'wisr aaron'
SELECT ID FROM Data WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE CONTAINS(*, @Name)
```

I get an error message

> ```
> Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 5
> Syntax error near 'aaron' in the full-text search condition 'wisr aaron'.
> ```

Msg 7630 suggest that

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(80)           = 'wisr near aaron'
SELECT ID FROM Data WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE CONTAINS(*, @Name)
```

is the solution. I tried running it. It did not crash but there were not results either.

Is there a way to do this without having to add `NEAR` all over the place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add double quotes if you wanna look for words with a space.

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(80)           = '"wisr aaron"'
```

But I doubt you will get any result if the `NEAR` version didn't get anything... (maybe rebuild your index ?)